# Where is my button?

Tags: android, flash, haxe, openfl

I'm new to haxe/openfl and am trying to simply put a button on a screen. The code below gives me a white screen, no button or reaction to a screen press via trace. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
package;

import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.Lib;
import openfl.Assets;
import flash.display.Sprite;


class Main extends Sprite {

public function new () {

 super ();
var sprite = new Sprite();
var bitmapData = Assets.getBitmapData ("images/button.png");
var bitmap = new Bitmap ( bitmapData );
sprite.addChild( bitmap );

// you may need to draw the hitarea

sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xff,0);    //transparent
sprite.graphics.lineStyle( 0,0xff, 0); //transparent

// may need to wait for image to load before using width, height - add
// check if required?

sprite.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height );
sprite.graphics.endFill();

   sprite.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e: MouseEvent){
   trace('clicked');} );        

}   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is not visible because you didn't add the sprite containing the button to the stage.

You should add it with something like `Lib.stage.addChild(sprite)`